# How to type N array of strings with TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
const rows: Row[] = [
  [
    1,
    ["breakfast", "apples"],
  ],
  [
    2,
    ["lunch", "burguer"],
    ["dinner", "pasta"],
  ],
];
```

The array can have any number of items, each one is an array itself with the first item always being a number and the rest being arrays of 2 strings.

This is the type I came up with:

```
type Row = [number, ...[string, string]];
```

But it's not working, it says that the 2nd item should be a string instead of an array of strings:

> Type '[string, string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Here's a [playground with an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdygXigbQHYFcC2AjCAJwBooA6CgZ2EIEsMBzNAXWYG4AoDgYzg2qiFElAFyxELFOg5Rps2QEZiM%20WgBEeAIYZtmymtJrNYMABsI%205svno11CJoDWBqBqyEGWImqsrfstBVZACZrVTU4Qm0GCBc1cxw%20HzCAtTBaAC8MzTiwPWAc-yhfdiA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [rest element in a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) should be of the form `[...YourDesiredElementType[]]`.  You want elements to be `[string, string]`, so the rest element looks like `...[string, string][]`:

```
type Row = [number, ...[string, string][]];
```

And then things work as desired:

```
const rows: Row[] = [
  [
    1,
    ["bananas", "apples"],
    ["steak", "burguer"],
  ],
  [
    2,
    ["orange", "lemon"],
    ["pizza", "pasta"],
  ],
]; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdygXigbQHYFcC2AjCAJwBooA6CtAZ2EIEsMBzUm+pgXTXfYG4AoPgGM4GGlEKIqALliIuKdHyiLlygIzElqtACI8AQwyH9VHaR36wYADYRT7TavQ6aEfQGszUPVkKMsRDoOWsHKaFrKAEyO2jpwhIaMEF46tjgiQTFhOmB0AF55+ilgJsBFoVDBvEA)